# .htaccess in Symfony2-based website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I've installed Piwik on the root of my Symfony2-based website (which should accessible at mywebsite.com/piwik/index.php) and I've tried to configure my .htaccess file so I can get around the 'No route found for "GET /piwik/index.php"' exception.

The problem is I am not good enough at configuring .htaccess, as a result I still get the above exception. Of course, I have to read tutorials. This is how I have tried to configure my .htaccess file:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^piwik/ - [L] 
    RewriteBase /        
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony ships with this rewrite rule as a default in `web/.htaccess`:

```
# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
```

So you should be able to drop the `piwik/` directory within the `web/` directory (thus, index.php will be `[SymfonyAppRoot]/web/piwik/index.php`) and access the page there.

By doing this, you allow Apache to serve `/piwik/index.php` before Symfony has a chance to get in the way.

Comment: Many thanks, @HPierce! It's working perfectly, you've made my day!

Comment: I have come to find out the app.php is no longer been reached, as a result I'm have the following exception whenever I request any resource: "The requested URL /mywebsite/web/diapers was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: @PatrickBass, That's odd. The rewrite rule I've highlighted here would not change that behavior. Without knowing anything more than you've posted here, I suspect you may have inadvertently changed one of the other defaults in .htaccess. I'd recommend you find a fresh copy of the default .htaccess that ships with Symfony and see what happens with that.

Comment: thanks again for your remark. Finally I manage to fix the issue by combining your approach and mine. I have reconfigured my .htaccess file as before (see my first code above) putting it in web/ folder and kept /piwik folder in /web as you advised.